# drupal 7 not rendering custom region

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, render, region

My issue is that I added a new region to my .info file for a second sidebar. After, I attached blocks to it in the structure > blocks area. Lastly in the page.tpl I had it render it via

```
<?php print render($page['sidebar_second']); ?>
```

It worked originally, then I moved everything to a new domain, copied all the files reattached all the blocks but now it doesn't render at all.

here's the .info file

```
regions[sidebar_first] = Sidebar first
regions[sidebar_second] = Sidebar second
regions[sidebar_bob] = Sidebar B0b!
```

[Here's the attached blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vOo9.png) as they appear under Structure > Blocks

Lastly I printed out

```
<pre><?=print_r($page,1)?></pre>
```

and here it's showing that [sidebar_second is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7t5ve.png)

Lastly I created a block that's a simple red div with 200px dimensions that should show up on every page, so I have no idea why it's not appearing.

Comment: Have you disabled and re-enabled the template files? Drupal will only list the regions on initial activation. Also clearing the cache might work.

Comment: Are there any conditions on which pages (or to which users) the blocks you created should appear?

Comment: Have you checked the html markup for confirming the red block is not printed? or you just visually checked the rendered html. If there are no contents and the height of the div happens to be zero then it wont be visible.

 Many themes don't print the region if its empty, so have you while maybe ( am assuming ) you copied that condition too into your theme?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing the theme registry? In the past, this has been my next step when clearing the cache seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the following line exists in your `page.tpl.php`:

```
<?php print render($page['sidebar_second']);?>
```

Comment: Isn't this exactly what he says he has in that file in his first code segment?